# OutOfMemoryException in WCF caused by memory fragmentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, tcp, out-of-memory

I made a simple 32 bit test project, just a counter function. The client creates several threads to call the function all the time. I used 30 threads to run, after 3 minutes(Or the count up to 20000), Server memory was fragmented(Made a dump file, Using WinDbg to open it,enter !address -summary can see free Largest Region by Usage is 64kb), direct stopping client debugging,the server may throw OutOfMemoryException. Please tell me what happened and how to resole this problem. 
Thanks.

Server code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tcpAddress = new Uri("net.tcp://localhost:9998/wcf");
            using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(DataProvider), tcpAddress))
            {
                host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IData), new NetTcpBinding(), "");
                host.Opened += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Service is running..."); };
                host.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "WCF.Demo")]
    public interface IData
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetCounter();
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class DataProvider : IData
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }

        public string GetCounter()
        {
            return string.Format(" counter = {0} test test test test test test test test test test test test test test",
                ++Counter);
            //return ++Counter;
        }
    }
}
```

Client Code

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Threading;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly CancellationTokenSource Cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread count：");
            var threadCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var cf = new ChannelFactory<IData>(new NetTcpBinding(), 
                new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9998/wcf"));
            for (var i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    var name = Thread.CurrentThread.Name;
                    var proxy = cf.CreateChannel();
                    while (!Cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                        Console.WriteLine("{2}: {0}\t{1}", name, proxy.GetCounter(),
                            DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
                    }

                    ((IChannel)proxy).Close();

                }) { Name = "thread " + i, IsBackground = true }.Start();
            }
            Console.Read();
            //Cts.Cancel();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "WCF.Demo")]
    public interface IData
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetCounter();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've run your code and didn't observe any problems with it.  Memory was being recycled nicely.

Comment: Integer contract cannot always show the exception, I put the contract into string.